# SSIS Deployment to Azure SQL Server, reference System.Net.Http.Formatting version 5.2.3.0 could not be found

Tags: c#, api, ssis, azure-sql-database

I am building an SSIS package to move data from TalentLMS to our company Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM). A script component source is used to retrieve the data.

This project was built with target SQL Server 2019, before I had to change it to SQL Server 2017 to allow it to work on Microsoft SQL Azure.

SSIS project was deployed using "SSIS in SQL Server" through Visual Studio 2019.

Specs: Visual Studio 2019, SSIS Project target SQL Server 2017 currently, System.Net.Http.Formatting 5.2.3.0, Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8   Nov  8 2022 12:27:23

There is a reference being used "System.Net.Http.Formatting, Version=5.2.3.0" for a line of code in the script on line 114 to be able to read content as async.

Line 114 reads the response content result as async to a class list
[image: Line 114 reads the response content result as async to a class list]

When executing the package in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio it returns an System.IO.FileNotFoundException of being unable to locate System.Net.Http.Formatting.

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http.Formatting, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

[image: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http.Formatting, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.]

When adding the System.Net.Http.Formatting reference, I had registered it to the local cache through VS Powershell using gacutil /i command.

In the .csproj file, this is how the reference is setup for System.Net.Http.Formatting.

```
<Reference Include="System.Net.Http.Formatting, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>C:\User\Company\AppData\Local\Temp\Vsta\SSIS_SC150\Vsta28GF9wnYy0SZpmPmrHykZg\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client.5.2.3\lib\net45\System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll</HintPath>
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
```

I have tried setting the System.Net.Http.Formatting to Copy Local to true. Prior to deploying it to the SQL server with no effect.

Could I get some advice on how to resolve this error?

I am also open to changing the code on line 114 to not use System.Net.Http.Formatting if it can return a list of class from the response.

Comment: Wherever the SSIS package is running needs to have the System.Net.Http.Formatting GAC'ed. I'm not familiar with the `deployed using "SSIS in SQL Server" through Visual Studio` option means, can you help me understand? Are you deploying to a Managed Instance or is this part of an ADF SSIS Integration Runtime?

Comment: @billinkc                                                                                                                        The SSIS project is being deployed through Visual Studio to a Microsoft Azure Pay-As-You-Go SQL Server. In Visual Studio, we're using the Integration Services Deployment Wizard to deploy the entire project with "SSIS in SQL Server" set as the deployment target and SQL Server Authentication for access. We have created a SSISDB on the SQL Server side to use the SSIS packages.  This is our first project attempting this.

Comment: Not trying to be dense, but is that SQL Server a [Managed Instance](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/products/azure-sql/managed-instance/), [Azure SQL](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/products/azure-sql/managed-instance/) , an Azure VM running SQL Server, something else? To my knowledge, SSIS can be deployed  to your custom VM or to an [Azure-SSIS integration runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/create-azure-ssis-integration-runtime) which then supports Azure SQL DB or an Managed Instance.

Comment: If SSIS-IR, then you'll need to use a custom setup to gac the assemblies https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-configure-azure-ssis-ir-custom-setup

Comment: @billinkc It's Azure SQL. Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8

Comment: We were able to resolve the issue by removing System.Net.Http.Formatting and switching over to Newtonsoft.JSON code to replace the code of line 114.

Comment: Good deal. Feel free to pop that as an answer so future seekers can make use of your knowledge